# How to stop Virtual Box error during a sudo apt-get update command?

Tags: kali-linux, virtualbox

I'm on Kali 2023.4 and I installed VirtualBox on it. I'm not sure if I did it wrong or something but now whenever I run the `sudo apt-get update` command I get the below response on top of whatever else gets updated. I'm just trying to stop it from trying every time I run the command. I've attempted to add all the virtual box packages to the `apt-mark hold` command but it still does it.

Any help is appreciated, Thank you.

```
Get:1 https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bullseye InRelease [7735 B]
Err:1 https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bullseye InRelease      
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A2F683C52980AECF
Hit:2 http://mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu/kali kali-rolling InRelease      
Hit:3 https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian stable InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bullseye InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A2F683C52980AECF
E: The repository 'https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bullseye InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: you're trying to install debian packages on Kali. [that doesn't work](https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/#non-kali-repositories). To cite Kali's docs: `dding other operating system’s repositories into Kali (such as trying to put Ubuntu on Kali), will break your installation. This is the single most common reason why Kali Linux systems break.` So, simply speaking . you can't.

Comment: And quite frankly speaking, you *should not be using Kali for what you're doing!* [Please read Kali's documentation on what Kali is **not** for!](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/)

Comment: Actually. Kali has an [official](https://www.kali.org/docs/virtualization/install-virtualbox-host/) guide on how to install VirtualBox on Kali as the host machine. So you CAN do it and it IS possible. I may have not done it properly with the separate repository but I'm still learning to work with Linux systems and it didn't brake the system so its okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the error, you need to remove the entries referencing download.virtualbox.org in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

To install VirtualBox, you don’t need to install a third-party repository; packages are [available in Kali](https://pkg.kali.org/pkg/virtualbox):

```
sudo apt install virtualbox
```